# Unsure how to import module from Python Standard Library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working through some exercises in Learning Python the Hard Way (LPTHW) and I am having some trouble while attempting to write some original code for a text-game I have made.

My issue is importing the "random" module from the python standard library.

The problem stems from NOT having my .py file in the main Python27 directory.

My question: How do I tell my script where to look for the file? And if I am using a real path, how can I prevent an error when another user tries to run my script and their root python27 directory is in a different location?

Any information or resources to study this would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Importing `random` should work like a charm. However, if you want your .py file to be accesible, you'll need to either set your `PYTHONPATH` to where you're storing it or create a package. Can you share any of the errors you're getting and what OS you're using?

Comment: I should also share that when I put my .py script into the main directory the function does work sucessfully. But that should not be a permanent solution. This would create a nightmare for directory management.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You certainly shouldn't need to put your script anywhere -- for example, does `python -c "import random;print random.randint(0,10)"` work?

Comment: Please post the directory structure of your module as well as some code samples.

Comment: C:\Python27\Python\LPTHW\randomexample.py

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: make sure that there are no random.py files in the directory you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've somehow messed up your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, it doesn't matter at all where you've stored your script. `import random` should always work.

However, if you have a script named `random.py` in the same directory as your current script, then Python will attempt to import that first, before hitting the other paths that eventually lead to the standard library. Could that be your problem?

Comment: I am still fairly new so I'm not sure I understand your answer. I don't know how to set a PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: @HarrisonBoles: All the better, so it's unlikely you have damaged it. What error message, exactly, are you getting? Please post the entire traceback - [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19574683/edit) your question to do so.

Comment: As it turns out I did have an old file named random.py inside LPTHW from a pervious exercise. THanks for the help everyone, I was very confused. The script is working fine now.

Comment: @HarrisonBoles: Yes, my crystal ball is working exceptionally fine tonight :)